# How to get queued item content inside Laravel 7 Job?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs, laravel-7

I have some jobs queued using dispatch then when i run

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=queue_name
```

I would like to print or log the contents of the item which is currently being processed by the handle function. What is the getter or property on the job class or how do i get the json string that i dispatched into the redis store from the handle function context?

```
public function handle($job, $next)
{
    print_r($job);
    print_r($next);

    Log::emergency(print_r($job, true));
    Log::emergency(print_r($next, true));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You're probably looking for the [payload](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.html#method_payload) method.

Comment: @digitalDrifter wouldn't it be smarter to actually provide an answer instead of solving it in the comments? :)